# Defining webapp styles in central maven project

Tags: java, css, maven, reusability

Is there a possibility to place a web-app style (CSS files and images) in a reusable maven project? To use this "style-projects" with other WAR projects.

Best regards

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a war-packaged project as a dependency in maven. This is called a "war overlay". It means that your resulting war file is a combination of the files from the dependency and your project copied over them:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html